# Expression tree creation from postfix expression

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Given a postfix expression, construct an expression tree. Looking code code review, optimizations and best practices.

```
public class ExpressionTree {

    private final String postfix;
    private TreeNode root;

    /**
     * Takes in a valid postfix expression and later its used to construct the expression tree.
     * The posfix expression, if invalid, leads to invalid results 
     * 
     * @param postfix   the postfix expression.
     */
    public ExpressionTree(String postfix) {
        if (postfix == null) { throw new NullPointerException("The posfix should not be null"); }
        if (postfix.length() == 0)  { throw new IllegalArgumentException("The postfix should not be empty"); } 
        this.postfix = postfix;
    }

    private static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        char ch;
        TreeNode right;

        TreeNode(TreeNode left, char ch, TreeNode right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.ch = ch;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }


    private boolean isOperator(char c) {
        return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
    }


    /**
     * Constructs an expression tree, using the postfix expression
     */
    public void createExpressionTree() {
        final Stack<TreeNode> nodes = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {
            char ch  = postfix.charAt(i);
            if (isOperator(ch)) {
               TreeNode rightNode = nodes.pop();
               TreeNode leftNode = nodes.pop();
               nodes.push(new TreeNode(leftNode, ch, rightNode));
            } else {
                nodes.add(new TreeNode(null, ch, null));
            }
        }
        root = nodes.pop();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the prefix notation
     * 
     * @return the prefix notation
     */
    public String prefix() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The root is empty, the tree has not yet been constructed.");
        }

        final StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
        preOrder(root, prefix);
        return prefix.toString();
    }

    private void preOrder(TreeNode node, StringBuilder prefix) {
        if (node != null) {
            prefix.append(node.ch);
            preOrder(node.left, prefix);
            preOrder(node.right, prefix);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the infix expression
     * 
     * @return  the string of infix.
     */
    public String infix() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The root is empty, the tree has not yet been constructed.");
        }
        final StringBuilder infix = new StringBuilder();
        inOrder(root, infix);
        return infix.toString();
    }

    private void inOrder(TreeNode node, StringBuilder infix) {
        if (node != null) {
            inOrder(node.left, infix);
            infix.append(node.ch);
            inOrder(node.right, infix);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExpressionTree expressionTree1 = new ExpressionTree("AB*CD/+");
        expressionTree1.createExpressionTree();
        assertEquals("+*AB/CD", expressionTree1.prefix());
        assertEquals("A*B+C/D", expressionTree1.infix());

        ExpressionTree expressionTree2 = new ExpressionTree("ABC+*D/");
        expressionTree2.createExpressionTree();
        assertEquals("/*A+BCD", expressionTree2.prefix());
        assertEquals("A*B+C/D", expressionTree2.infix());        

        ExpressionTree expressionTree3 = new ExpressionTree("ABCD/+*");
        expressionTree3.createExpressionTree();
        assertEquals("*A+B/CD", expressionTree3.prefix());
        assertEquals("A*B+C/D", expressionTree3.infix());
    }
}
```

Comment: It way not be part of your problem definition, but the infix notation you currently output is ambiguous. You should consider adding brackets: `"ABC+*D/"` => `"((A*(B+C))/D)"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Make your structs immutable**
`TreeNode` is a helper structure, with public members, which is fine, but you better make them `final`, so you know they won't be changed after the object is created.

**Choose your validations**
Don't throw `NullPointerException` on your own. It may confuse a future debugger. Either throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or let the runtime throw the `NullPointerException` for you.

**Choose your comments**
Most of your comments do not add much to the methods, and are therefore redundant. Let the names of the method and variables do the work for you. If you feel the name `prefix` is not clear enough on its own, it is better to rename it (maybe to `toPrefixNotation()`) and then you can safely remove your comments.

**Being nice is better than being strict**
Unless there is some requirement restriction, I don't think you need to throw an exception if `root` is `null` - why not simply call `createExpressionTree()` instead of telling the developer *he* should?
Since there is no meaning for calling `createExpressionTree()` twice (`postfix` is `final`...), you might as well hide it altogether, and call it when needed.

**Use the power of String**
Use `String#indexOf` to make `isOperator` more succinct:

```
private boolean isOperator(char c) {
    return "+-*/".indexOf(c) != -1
}
```

Comment: +1 for *choose your validations*, +1 for methods explicit names, +1 for automatic call to `createExpressionTree()`. -1 I don't really like using `indexOf()` like this, because it gets away from its initial meaning, thus reducing readability. Also it might be worse in terms of performance, but it's just a guess here.